Why does Rust require the use of a closure (aka lambda function) when spawning a thread?
Rust requires the use of a closure when spawning a thread for all but the simplest of functions.
Example:
std::thread::spawn(
    move || {
        target_function(/* parameters ... */);
    }
)

(The exception is when a function has no arguments, in which case a target function can be used directly, without enclosing it within a closure.)
But why does Rust require the use of closures when spawning a function? Is this a convenience for language designers? Language users?

as opposed to what? What else would you have instead of a closure?

@njzk2 C++ uses functions to start a thread function

@user2138149 C++ has variable arity / varargs, Rust does not. So std::thread::spawn only accepts 0-argument functions. As a result you can either give it a 0-argument named function, or "adapt" an n-arguments function via a closure.

thanks for clarifying. It could be useful to add an example of that to your question, to indicate what you'd be expecting. (Using lambdas or function references feels pretty standard coming from Python, Java, and a few others, but I haven't touched C++ in 20 years)

Ok thanks I think that explains the reason. Couldn't that be solved with a macro though?

eg; println! is varaidic (kind of)

println! is variadic because it has variadic requirements (and needs to be procedural besides so it can't be a function in the first place). A macro around spawn would be a lot of weird complexity and behaviour, to gain all of... 6 characters, or thereabout? In the specific case where you need a move closure, otherwise it's just 2?

And then why special-case spawn that way and not Iterator::map? Or Option::filter? Does that mean every HOF needs to be paired with a macro?

@Masklinn in the variadic macro you just internally create a lambda that moves both the input function and the arguments and calls the input function with the arguments, this becomes the new argument to spawn, type-checking will done, etc ... there is nothing technically preventing this.

@AhmedAEK of course there is nothing preventing it, but is this actually useful and beneficial in any way? Is spawn_somethingsomething!(foo, bar, baz) an actual improvement over spawn(|| foo(bar, baz))?

@Masklinn well, python and C++ have it and people like it, why not rust ?

@AhmedAEK they don't "have it", they have varargs and / or overloading as part of the core language, Rust has neither. And they also have dynamic typing, unchecked templates, constructors, implicit conversions, ..., should Rust have that?

I don't necessarily think one or the other is better. My curioscity came from the fact that every piece of Rust code you see which uses thread::spawn for some reason has a closure defined to spawn the thread. This is highly unusual - so it's interesting to know what the reason for it is.


The exception is when a function has no arguments, in which case a target function can be used directly, without enclosing it within a closure.

Yes, because then you're, well, passing in the function, and not the result of its call.
Consider the difference between
foo(bar);

and
foo(bar(quux));

– in the latter case, bar(quux) is evaluated eagerly first, and its retval (whatever it is – in this case it'd likely have to be a 0-argument (0-arity) function) passed to foo.
With something like
foo(|| bar(quux));

a 0-argument (0-arity) function is passed to foo, and it's at liberty to call it, or not call it, as it likes. Or, you know, spawn a thread that eventually calls it.

But why does Rust require the use of closures when spawning a function?

As you yourself saw, it doesn't, but that's the way you partially apply a function (in this case to reduce its arity to zero so it's passable to spawn).

I can see that my question clearly did not make any sense. I will try to edit it.

I think I'm going to have to ask a different question tbh, it seems like this one is being interpreted in a radically different way to how I intended

In some programming languages, instead of supplying a functional object when creating
new thread, you can supply a function pointer, and a separate list of arguments. E.g., in Python, you can write Thread(target=bar, args=(quux,)). I think maybe @user2138149 was aksing why Rust is not like that.

@SolomonSlow yes - kind of. The question was more why a lambda, since no other languages seem to need to use this, although they often can choose to. Your example from Python is also a good example of another solution which can be used. Again, Python does not require a lambda function.

That has pretty much been answered in the comments under the question however.

You can also write Thread(target=partial(bar, quux)) or Thread(target=lambda: bar(quux)) in Python, but that's because typing there is looser and Thread() accepts any callable (but will fail later on if you pass in the wrong args/kwargs). That's not the case in Rust.

History. Rust had closures from the early days of the language and is fundermentally descended from the functional ML tradition via OCaml. C++ was originally developed as an extension of C, and its templates were designed more as an improvement on textual preprocessor rather than any formal theory.
In this context, it makes sense that rust would make use of the functional idiom of partial application, passing a partially applied (closed over) function to the spawn. Then spawn has a uniform api that automatically includes the capability to pass additional arguments without anything special.
C++ only got closures relatively recently, and until then the standard was the c idiom of explicitly passing a function plus extra data, with the template varargs to help with extra data. This idiom fits with the c++ model of offering minimal abstraction over the underlying representation.
In terms of implemention it doesn't make any difference, as rust closures compile to a function pointer + extra data when used as a dynamic object, the same as the c++ representation.
